# Amazon S3: Monitor my bucket's current disk and bandwidth usage using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to create basic script using PHP so I can be alerted (by email for example) if a specific bucket is already using 100GB disk or 100GB bandwidth from Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1):

You can use amazon's php library to get the size of a bucket programatically.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_bucket_filesize
is an example of how to do it. 
Using the example above you can create a simple function that gets the sizes of all your buckets.  If they are over your size threshold you can send yourself an email.  If you're on a unix based os you can set up crontab to have this script run every x amount of time.

Amazon might offer email notifications on bandwidth usage already.  Did you do any investigating yourself??

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible to set up metrics for S3

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html#cloudwatch-monitoring-accessing

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-delete-notifications-better-filters-bucket-metrics/